# Is there a simple way in HTML to stack photos of various dimensions in two columns by always filling first the column that has more blank space

Tags: html, css, stack, alignment

is there a simple way to fill two columns of width 50% each with photos, by always adding the next photo in the column that has more blank space?

Photos have various dimensions but should fit the width columns.

Comment: You should provide the code example to make it more understandable

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you a more in-depth answer without a code example or more information about context, but the crucial pieces of information you need are the width of each column in pixels, and the width of elements in the lowermost row in those columns. This is assuming you're stacking from left-to-right and then moving downward.

There are [various functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Determining_the_dimensions_of_elements) to determine element width using JavaScript.

Comment: Hello Thanks for your answer. I wanted to avoid adding any JavaScript (or TypeScript since I am working on Angular) code. For the context: I have photos of architecture projects that are sorted from most recent to oldest. I want to show them on two columns, but with the most recent on top and the oldest at the bottom. Right now, all I was able to do is fill the first column, than the second one. I need to fill them in parallel. Also, I want to keep the original  height/width ratio of the photos (otherwise I would just use a grid). Do you think this is doable with CSS and HTML? Thank you again.

Comment: Also, columns width is flexible (depending on the screen width).